# My CSS animation is working but not properly

Tags: html, css

I've linked my html page to a minify css file provided by animate.css and it is supposed to make a picture of div5 rotate according to the center of the picture. But instead, the picture is rotating in a circle. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Below are the codes from both the html and css files:

```css
div .div5 img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  left: 230px;
}

div .rotateOut {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="middle">
  <div class="center-portfolio">
    <h3>&emsp;Portfolio</h3>
    <hr>
    <div class="div1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/UKBsvV0.jpg" height="120px" width="150px"></div>
    <div class="div2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/TSiyiJv.jpg" height="120px" width="150px"></div>
    <div class="div3"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZKMnXce.png" height="120px" width="150px"></div>
    <div class="div4"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/IjlfeYO.jpg" height="120px" width="150px"></div>
    <div class="rotateOut div5"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/fqgm8uh.png" height="120px" width="150px"></div>
    <div class="div6"></div>
    <div class="banner1">career picture 1</div>
    <div class="banner2">chocolate tour</div>
    <div class="banner3">Abidjan</div>
    <div class="banner4">career picture 2</div>
    <div class="banner5">Guild Brussels</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: They is something missing in your code. No animation are defined

Comment: It is in the head section of the html file as:   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css">

Comment: Please put your soultion to JSFiddle and use animate.css there to reproduce your problem, also replace HTML <img> sources for images if possible(you can just put some placeholders there).

Comment: @vicodin, do not use external product like JSFiddle or Codepen when you can use the internal code system

Comment: @Arthur oh, thank you for pointing out. I see now that you already added external library as a link tag

Comment: I've just edited my code and you can see my problem visually. The placeholder is rotating in a circle instead of rotating about its center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to animate.css [docs](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css), you should add `animated` class to the div:

```css
div .div5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  left: 230px;
}

div .rotateOut {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="middle">
  <div class="center-portfolio">
    <h3>&emsp;Portfolio</h3>
    <hr>
    <div class="div1"><img src="http://placehold.jp/24/cc9999/993333/150x100.png"></div>
    <div class="div2"><img src="http://placehold.jp/24/cc9999/993333/150x100.png"></div>
    <div class="div3"><img src="http://placehold.jp/24/cc9999/993333/150x100.png"></div>
    <div class="div4"><img src="http://placehold.jp/24/cc9999/993333/150x100.png"></div>
    <div class="animated rotateOut div5"><img src="http://placehold.jp/24/cc9999/993333/150x100.png"></div>
    <div class="div6"></div>
    <div class="banner1">career picture 1</div>
    <div class="banner2">chocolate tour</div>
    <div class="banner3">Abidjan</div>
    <div class="banner4">career picture 2</div>
    <div class="banner5">Guild Brussels</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, note that you've assigned `position: absolute` to the image. If you will assign it to your div, it will spin across own origin.

You can run my code snippet and see that it works.

Comment: where did you change the position?

Comment: I didn't change position. I removed `img` from your css selector. 
It was `div .div5 img` and become `div .div5`

(btw, you can use just `.div5` here

Comment: You can use `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to animate it just once

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working now. You're the bossman my man!

Comment: So my answer is working, but you marked other one as a solution? @Leealp

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this site and don't know how things work. I just checked you also as the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's the problem because we didn't have any code for animation, but this may be caused because of div's origin are not well placed.

Take a look to [CSS TRansform-origin](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp)

Comment: Just a comment was enough until OP clarifies :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien my comment was only to inform that code was missing, but this answer was to propose the transform-origin solution.